# TensorFlow Api Dataset: performance guide?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have question about performance guide for using Dataset API in TensorFlow. I have following code:

```
output_path =  "train_data_full_encoded_4.tfrecords"
batch_size  = 16
output_buffer_size = batch_size * 100
dataset            = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(output_path)
src_tgt_dataset    = dataset.shard(1, 0)
src_tgt_dataset    = src_tgt_dataset.shuffle(output_buffer_size, 44)
src_tgt_dataset    = src_tgt_dataset.map(_parse_record, num_parallel_calls=4).prefetch(output_buffer_size)
src_tgt_dataset    = src_tgt_dataset.map(_random_crop_filp, num_parallel_calls=4).prefetch(output_buffer_size)
src_tgt_dataset    = src_tgt_dataset.map(_make_labels_small, num_parallel_calls=None).prefetch(output_buffer_size)

import time
dataset = src_tgt_dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.repeat(1)
end    = time.time()
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)) as sess:
    batched_iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    images, scores, geomaps, trainingmask = batched_iter.get_next()
    sess.run(batched_iter.initializer)
    idx = 0
    while True:
        try:
            raw_images, raw_scores, raw_geomaps, raw_trainingmask = sess.run([images, scores, geomaps, trainingmask])

        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
print  idx, time.time() - end
```

My problem is slow speed of reading the data, it took ~0.2s per batch which make utilization of GPU low. I would like to speed it up, this is why I created TfRecords. It works faster than normal loader but still I cannot get constantly >60% of utilization.

How could I speed up data loading? Maybe there are some performance guide? I curious if setting `num_parallel_calls` at different `map` function have any influence of final speed (I have tried several version and current one seems to be the fastest).

Also for creating TfRecord I use images encoded to JPEG and PNG, but not using `tf.image.encode_jpeg` and `tf.image.encode_png` because I have a memory problem using them (this process eat all 16GB, but when using `PIL`  to encode image, memory usage was correct), any hint on that ? Here is my code for creating the TfRecords using TF.

```
def createRecord(folder_with_annotation, idx, files):
    output_path = os.path.join(folder_with_annotation, "train_data_full_encoded_{}.tfrecords".format(idx))
    writer      = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_path)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        for f in tqdm(files):
            img, score_map, geo_map, training_mask = preprocessImage(f)
            h, w, c = img.shape

        image_tf      = tf.image.encode_jpeg(tf.constant(img),format='rgb').eval(session=sess)

        score_map_tf     = tf.image.encode_jpeg(tf.constant(score_map),format='grayscale').eval(session=sess)
        training_mask_tf = tf.image.encode_jpeg(tf.constant(training_mask),format='grayscale').eval(session=sess)
        geo_map_part_one = tf.image.encode_png(tf.constant(geo_map)).eval(session=sess)

        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                    'height': _int64_feature(h),
                    'width': _int64_feature(w),
                    'depth': _int64_feature(c),
                    'multiply_geo_map': _int64_feature(multiply),
                    'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image_tf),
                    'score_map_raw': _bytes_feature(score_map_tf),
                    'geo_map_raw': _bytes_feature(geo_map_part_one),
                    'training_mask_raw': _bytes_feature(training_mask_tf),
                    }))

        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

# All examples saved
writer.close()
```

Edit: I resolved issue with memory when creating the TfRecord with does not growing the graph (and running `eval` done that). I will inform after getting the result of reading speed when using `tf.encode` function.
Edit2: As I supposed, this does not decrease a time of reading the data (but size of TfRecord is smaller).